# How to display information that is allocated in another table using ruby?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I created three models, one named Student, another one Cclass, and the last named Enrollment.

I have a many to many relationship where many students can have many classes and vice-versa. I wanted to fix this many to many relationship, so I created a new model named enrollment - it is supposed to display both the students in the database and the classes like this:

------ **Class** ------------------ **Student** 
1. **Class_name** ------   1. **Student_name**

At least something like that, but I am not able to display the information from both of the tables in the Enrollment's class.

**This is my student.rb**

```
class Student < ApplicationRecord

attr_accessor :FirstName

has_many :enrollments
has_many :cclasses, through: :enrollments
```

end

**This is my class.rb**

```
class Cclass < ApplicationRecord

attr_accessor :Name

has_many :enrollments
has_many :students, through: :enrollments
```

end

**This is my enrollment.rb**

```
class Enrollment < ApplicationRecord

belongs_to :student
belongs_to :cclass

end
```

**This is my enrollments_controller.rb**

```
class EnrollmentsController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @enrollment = Enrollment.all
  end

  def show
    @enrollment = Enrollment.find(params[:Student_id, :Cclass_id])
  end

  def new
    @enrollment.new
  end

  def update
  end

  def create
  end

  def edit
  end

  def destroy
  end

  private
    def enrollment_params
      params.require(:enrollment).permit(:Student_id, :Cclass_id)
    end
end
```

**This is my index.html.erb for my enrollment model**

```
 <h1> Enrollment's Index </h1>

 <table>
    <tbody>
        <thead> Student and Classes Enrolled
            <th> Student </th>
            <th> Classes </th>
            <% Array(@enrollment).each do |e| %>
               <td><%= link_to e.student.FirstName %> </td>
               <td><%= link_to e.cclass.Name %> </td>
            <% end %>
        </thead>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

I do not know how to reference the First Name of the student and the name of the class. Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean under "I am not able to display the information from both of the tables in the Enrollment's class."? Do you see a blank page or do you see any errors in your server log? Why are you calling `Array(@enrollment)`? How about `Enrollment.all.each do |e|`? Also you if you want to have a student link and class link, then you should provide `link_to` method with corresponding student and class route.

Comment: Because I want to take the information from my student's table and my cclass' table and display them in enrollment's index page. I do not get any errors, just my HTML, but no information at all. I am using Array(@enrollment), because sometimes I get an error for .each. I have not tried Enrollment.all.each. Also I did try providing their correct routes and still no information was displayed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see a couple of things you can improve first make sure to use snake_case for symbols, methods, and variables. Also, use lower case as uppercase makes reference to classes and constants. Please see below:

Student Class:

```
class Student < ApplicationRecord
attr_accessor :first_name

has_many :enrollments
has_many :cclasses, through: :enrollments
```

Cclass class:

```
class Cclass < ApplicationRecord

attr_accessor :name

has_many :enrollments
has_many :students, through: :enrollments
```

In your enrollment controller#index you're calling the method `.all` and assigning it to a variable named `@enrollment` that is not reflecting the real value of the data that is storing. Since `Enrollment.all` return value is an array-type object that contains all the enrollments in your DB. So with that in mind.

Enrollment controller:

```
class EnrollmentsController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @enrollments = Enrollment.all
  end

  def show
    @enrollment = Enrollment.find(params[:student_id, :cclass_id])
  end

  def new
    @enrollment.new
  end

  def update
  end

  def create
  end

  def edit
  end

  def destroy
  end

  private
    def enrollment_params
      params.require(:enrollment).permit(:student_id, :cclass_id)
    end
end
```

Finally, for your `index.html.erb` file you have this line of code

`<% Array(@enrollment).each do |e| %>`

You don't need to call `Array` since you `@enrollments` variable that you've assigned in your controller action is already array-type object that responds to the method `each`.

```
<h1> Enrollment's Index </h1>

 <table>
    <tbody>
        <thead> Student and Classes Enrolled
            <th> Student </th>
            <th> Classes </th>
            <% @enrollments.each do |e| %>
               <td><%= link_to e.student.first_name %> </td>
               <td><%= link_to e.cclass.name %> </td>
            <% end %>
        </thead>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

If you have any questions let me know

Comment: Thank you Omar. Sorry I took so long to respond. I did that, but I still need to reference the information in other tables, since the code I have is not working (is not giving an error and is not displaying anything either).

Comment: Hi, Cristian do you have a repo on Github I can take a look at your code.

Comment: Yes, I was working on it, so it many not seem entirely correct. This is the link: https://github.com/Uriel1795/RRProject

Comment: Hello Omar, where you able to check it?

Comment: Hi, Cristian yes I was able to check it. I didn't find any info or data in your DB. That could be one of your problems. I'm off all day today if you want to we can screen share and work this out together.

Comment: Thats odd, because on my local database, I do have data in it. At what time do you want to screen share?